# Parsing JSON with 3 layers (object, array, string) in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

I'm not really familiar with parsing JSON Objects and I really need your guys' help with this. I know that the parsing I'm doing is wrong and I do not understand after reading sources online about parsing in Android Studio.

The code below is the parsing portion of my project.

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("translations");

            for (int i = 0;  i < jsonArray.length(); i++ ) {
                JSONObject translations = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String translatedText = translations.getString("translatedText");

                textView.append(translatedText);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The JSON Object I'm trying to parse is below:-

```
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "queso"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm told my code is not working as the first level of the JSON is a JSONObject "data" and not "translations" but I do not know how to modify the code to how it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been awhile since I've used the built in Android JSON objects, but my initial reaction is that you need to parse the JSON object "data" before parsing the JSON array "translations". Modifying your earlier code:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data"); // get data first
        JSONArray jsonArray = data.getJSONArray("translations"); // get the array from data

        for (int i = 0;  i < jsonArray.length(); i++ ) {
            JSONObject translations = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String translatedText = translations.getString("translatedText");

            textView.append(translatedText);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
JSONObject jsonData = response.getJSONObject("data");
if (jsonData != null) {
  JSONArray jsonArray = jsonData.getJSONArray("translations");

  for (int i = 0;  i < jsonArray.length(); i++ ) {
    JSONObject translations = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    String translatedText = translations.getString("translatedText");

    textView.append(translatedText);
  }
}
```